# Better way to run different db queries based on path in node.js and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'd like to have some advice on how to call different database queries based on the path in the url using `express.js`. Here's a working example code but I'm not sure if that is the good way of doing it:

`server.js`

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
Promise = require("bluebird"),
db = require('./db/managedb'); // database modules for sequelize.js

app.get('/p/:section/:optional?', function(req, res){ 

  var section = req.params["section"];
  var optional = req.params["optional"];

  if(section == "index"){

   Promise.props({

       main: db.db.query('CALL sp1()'),
       second: db.db.query("CALL sp2()")

    }).then(function(obj){ 
       res.render(section+'.html',obj) 
    }).catch(function (error) {
    })

  }else if(section == "overviews"){

   var page = req.query.page || 0;

   Promise.resolve(db.db.query('CALL sp3(:page)',{page:page})).then(function(d){
      res.render(section+'.html',d)
   })

  }else if(section == "reviews"){

   var page = req.query.page || 0;
   var review_id = req.query.review_id || 1; 

   Promise.resolve(db.db.query('CALL sp4(:review_id,:page)',{review_id:review_id,page:page})).then(function(d){
        res.render(section+'.html',d)
   })
  }
})
```

Is it an okay solution? My concern is that if I kept adding more conditions for new `section`s, it might be quite messy, but is there a better way to call different database queries based on the path? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's much commonality between the 3 sections, why not have 3 different routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use different routing handlers, like this:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app     = express(),
    Promise = require('bluebird'),
    db      = require('./db/managedb'); // database modules for sequelize.js

app.get('/p/index/:optional?', function(req, res) {
  Promise.props({

    main: db.db.query('CALL sp1()'),
    second: db.db.query('CALL sp2()')

  }).then(function(obj) {
    res.render('index.html', obj);
  }).catch(function(error) {
  });
});

app.get('/p/overviews/:optional?', function(req, res) {

  var page = req.query.page || 0;

  Promise.resolve(db.db.query('CALL sp3(:page)', {page: page})).then(function(d) {
    res.render('overviews.html', d);
  });
});

app.get('/p/reviews/:optional?', function(req, res) {

  var page = req.query.page || 0;
  var review_id = req.query.review_id || 1;

  Promise.resolve(db.db.query('CALL sp4(:review_id,:page)', {review_id: review_id, page: page})).then(function(d) {
    res.render('reviews.html', d);
  });
});
```

If you have more shared code between the routes, you could use multiple routing handlers using `next()` callbacks. For example, you could write your content from `d` somewhere into `req` and then just call `next()` instead of `res.render(…)`. You then add another routing handler with the same signature as your old one (matching all routes) below those three and call `res.render(section + '.html', req.d)` (or other code) in there.